# Problem during SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, port

I am trying to run ssh command from one machine to another and gets the following error message
**ssh: connect to host 10.22.254.70 port 22: Connection refused**
It is able to ping the same machine properly. I have ssh installed on both the machines.

Can anyone tell the solution to this problem.

Comment: By "I have ssh installed on both machines", did you mean, that you installed the ssh _server_ on one and an ssh _client_ on the other machine?

Comment: You have to install/start ssh server on the machine you are want to connect to.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow as it doesn't have anything to do with programming. It's better placed on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have start sshd service.

```
service  sshd start
```

Comment: It seems there was some problem with the installing part only. I re installed it and now it works properly.

Comment: ok. nice  , your problem is solved. 
This site is for programming question only . If you have setup or server config question please use appropriate site from ServerFault or SuperUser

Comment: Sorry for inappropriate question. Will take care in future.